# How to trigger a build based on TFVC label in VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I've been searching for this but have not been able to find something concrete.

Could someone please help whether it's possible to queue a build based on label in VSTS?

Link here - [Label in TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files)

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean a label ?

Comment: Please refer to this link, a label in TFS is the snapshot of current version -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Git**

If you are using Git version control you can use the tag as shown below. Git tags are quite nicely supported in web interface and builds.

Tag in commit
[image]

Selecting Tag when queuing build
[image]

Getting the source by tag for build
[image]

Build done for tag
[image]

**TFVC**

TFVC is not supporting label in Code tab of web interface. But it is supported in  Visual Studio.

Queuing a build for code in TFVC label should be prefixed by L. 
[image]

For my label "TFVCSampleLabel" a build is queued like shown below
[image]

Build done for Label

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!