# how to add tag(user story) to build process in tfs2017, If developer check in code

Tags: tfs, tags

In tfs 2017 dashboard tag how connect with after commit the code then it link build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check in code, you could directly select work item ID  in **Related Work Items**

[image]

Instead of entering ID, you could also drag work items here from a query result to link work item to check in.

[image]

Then when you set up a CI build in TFS, it will auto detect any check in/commit changeset. During the build it will auto add/link that related work item in changeset for build summary result. Such as below:

[image]

---

**Update:**

TFVC is not supporting label in Code tab of web interface. But it is supported in Visual Studio.
Queuing a build for code in TFVC label should be prefixed by L.

[image]

More details please refer this similar question: [How to trigger a build based on TFVC label in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089673/how-to-trigger-a-build-based-on-tfvc-label-in-vsts)

Comment: thank you for information,Actually How to add tag to particular build and  i am not seeing after build succeeded page that tag name?

Comment: Tag and user story are totally different things. User Story is a  work item type. For build tag. It's used to filter generated build like this doc mention https://roadtoalm.com/2016/07/08/controlling-build-quality-using-build-tags-and-vsts-release-management/.  If you are talking about something similar to git tag, tfvc do not have this, we do use **label**, you could add them in Visual Studio. And during the build, you could directly build label, details please kindly review this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089673/how-to-trigger-a-build-based-on-tfvc-label-in-vsts

Comment: @naguparimi My pleasure. If so kindly accept this answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @naguparimi When you create the work item, it auto generated. 
The unique identifier that is assigned to a work item. Work item IDs are unique across all team projects and within a team project collection. `Reference name=System.Id`, `Data type=Integer` . For example  643 is just the work item ID of user story in this sample link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#work-item-form You could also take a look at the detail form of this work item.